# Elasticsearch synonyms only for a certain field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES mapping that has `adjustment`, `organization` and `country` fields. I want to define synonyms for those specific fields such that, for example:

```
SA => Seasonally Adjusted # for adjustment
SA => Special Analysis # for organization
SA => Kingdom of Saudi Arabia # for country
```

(Note, this is a contrived example and not real data)

I guess this would happen at both index and query time?

How do I specify that the synonyms should be for a specific field, such that a search of `SA` would return all documents containing `Seasonally Adjusted` in `adjustment`, `Special Analysis` in `organization` or `Kingdom of Saudi Arabia` in `country`?

Also, can I do this with nested fields based on the nested document. So that the subdocument `{ type: country, value: SA }` and `{ type: organization, value: SA }` and `{ type: adjustment, value: SA }` would work correctly?

(ES 2.4)

Answer (score 0):

You may create custom analyzers for all the fields with custom synonym filter

For instance,

Analyzer :

```
        "country_text_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": "keyword",
           "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "country_synonym"
           ]
        }
```

Filter :

```
         "country_synonym" : {
            "type" : "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms/synonyms_countries.txt" //<-- this path is relative to ES_CONFIG location
         }
```

You may create similar analyzer/filters for all your fields which will provide desired behavior for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

`PUT test_index
    {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "synonym_adjustment": {
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                            "filter": ["lowercase","synonym_adjustment_filter"]
                        },
                        "synonym_organization": {
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                            "filter": ["lowercase","synonym_organization_filter"]
                        },
                        "synonym_country": {
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                            "filter": ["lowercase","synonym_country_filter"]
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "synonym_adjustment_filter": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms": ["SA => Seasonally Adjusted"]
                        },
                        "synonym_organization_filter": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms": ["SA => Special Analysis"]
                        },
                        "synonym_country_filter": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms": ["SA => Kingdom of Saudi Arabia"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "index_type_name": {
                "properties": {
                    "adjustment": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "default",
                        "search_analyzer": "synonym_adjustment"
                    },
                    "organization": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "default",
                        "search_analyzer": "synonym_organization"
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "default",
                        "search_analyzer": "synonym_country"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`